# Get method more than once under API gateway for single resource?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have to create three GET methods under the API gateway for one resource. Can anyone let me know how can I add more than one Get method? When I add one method, there is no option to add the second method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create three GET methods for one resource. How could it decide which one to use? You must handle that in your application logic.

Comment: According to my requirement, I have three get methods with different parameters. Now, If I have to handle the logic in my code, then users must have to apply all the parameters in the request?